# candump and cansniffer are working but cansend is not working on Raspberry Pi + RS485 CAN HAT (MCP2515)

Tags: raspberry-pi, can

I connect it at 500k bitrate. Both `candump` and `cansniffer` are working, receiving a lot of messages.

I've pinned down the packet that I want to replay, the ID is 39E.

`39E#0108210000100000` to lock the car door, and `39E#0008210000100000` to unlock.

But `cansend can0 39E#0108210000100000` does nothing. I tried to execute it in endless loop with some interval but the car still not responding.

By the way, while analyzing the messages,  `39E#0008210000100000` appears to repeated in `candump` in high speed.

Could it caused by the collision against the already exist message in CAN network? I want to send `39E#0108210000100000` but `39E#0008210000100000` is already repeated continuously in the network.

I've tried to repeated the command with no delay to make it fast but the car still not responding.

How to overcome this?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that this packet is the only thing that needs to be sent in order to unlock the car? There might be more to it, that you've missed. It sounds to me like the packet is being sent, just that the car doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the message is not being acknowledged, and the driver is repeating it. Can you try sending a different message that someone on the bus will ack to test your hardware setup?

Also some more details on your hardware will allow me to be a bit more specific with my answer - include your computer/OS, can adapter and wiring/termination.